# ResNet TFLearn ValueError:

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn, resnet

I am new to CNN, and I want to train resnet and here is my code:

[image]

And I got error:

[image]

I am not familiar with CNN, thus I do not know how to adjust my network. I think I need try to understand it first but for some reason I do not have much time. Is there anyone could help me?

I have 2287 lines, and each line have 908*908 float. I want to use 2000 lines as train data and the rest of data as test data.

Comment: Add script here (not images) to get better feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Error says you're trying feed a "x" with shape (64,824464) to tensor of shape (?,908,908,1)

You have to reshape your "x" (by the way not shown in the script) to (?,908,908,1)

You could use:

```
x = tf.reshape(x,[64,908,908,1])
```

Comment: my train_x is (2000,908,908,1) and my test_x is (287,908,908,1)
and I set batch_size=64.